# Encrypt and Decrypt data to file

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am sort of new to VB.Net and I was looking everywhere for a solution.

What I,m after is a way I can encrypt and decrypt information like checkbox values, textbox  text, etc and save it to a single file so when the form is loaded, it can check that file and set up their options as how they have set it up previously.

I want to encrypt this file so the data isn't visible so: if for example there was a textbox that had price: $20, if the file was ever loaded into notepad the info in there wouldn't be readable.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution to this is using the project settings. You can specify variables there and use them in your code. The values of the variables remain the same when you restart your program. You can use the settings in like this:

when loading the program:

```
textBox.Text = MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.TextBoxValue
```

when exiting Project:

```
MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.TextBoxValue = textBox.Text
MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.Save( )
```

In this example `MyProject`is the name of your project and TextBoxValue is the name of the setting. You can create settings in the projects properties.

To encrypt the settings you store you cold just use a secure string (for example):

```
var cypherText = "Some string to encrypt".ToSecureString().EncryptString();
var clearText = cypherText.DecryptString().ToInsecureString();
```

Comment: What about the security concern he raised?

Comment: @archer884: Forgot that part :-). But I've edited my post, so that it covers it now.

Comment: Cool! Was curious about that myself.